# GetThreadTimes, Windows Phone and Windows Store apps

Tags: winapi, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, query-performance

We have C/C++ library. The library has a high resolution timer used to do things like measuring throughput. The timer uses `GetThreadTimes` on Windows desktops and servers for measurements and to develop the statistics.

Windows Phone and Windows Store lack [`GetThreadTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms683237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but the MSDN page does not discuss its replacement for the platforms. I'm also having trouble locating information on the subject in MSDN (cf., ["windows phone" per thread performance counter site:microsoft.com](http://www.google.com/search&q="windows+phone"+per+thread+performance+counter+site%3Amicrosoft.com)).

What is the Windows Phone and Windows Store equivalent to `GetThreadTimes`?

---

It appears [QueryPerformanceCounter function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is available on both Windows Phone and Windows Store apps, but its not clear to me how to move to the next logical step of a particular thread's performance.